# Java parameterized tests with non-static parameters

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, testing, junit, integration-testing

I am currently working on creating a Parameterized Test with the parameters taken from JEE injected services.

The injected parameters are obtained from the DB, via the services. However, the service injection cannot be done in the static getParameters() method, because that getParameters() method is called way before the services can be resolved by the test instance. When the injection is called in the getParameters() method, the JVM cannot locate the context from which to resolve the injection.

The purpose is to have a general test which uses DB params and shows a new test case result (or failure) for each DB param.

Is there anyway in which to have this with non-static parameter resolving?

Are there any libraries which would display such test results without static parameter method?

Comment: If you need to run a test in context of a JEE container, try looking up Arquillian for testing purposes to run a test inside of an embedded container.

Comment: Would this provide a solution for my problem?
We already have a container. Is this container somehow different than standard containers?

Comment: Currently, you would access the database via JDBC or similar "by hand", right? Arquillian would re-use your container configuration and enable you to e.g. inject a service into your unit-test where you access the backend using methods you already use in production.